# Unintentional Iframeception and elements below Iframe are not visible

Tags: angular, iframe

My goal is to embed an angular web application url on Sharepoint. So I was following the instructions found in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXG54G7Nv8o&t=109s to create an embeddable iframe and I seem to be getting an odd error that my iframes keep being created within themselves
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hIAI.jpg). as well as any elements below it are removed even if the iframe is not being displayed. My Project structure is the same as the video's: having a home component that has the iframe and button to display the iframe on click and a widget component that has the information to be displayed on the iframe.

Here are some relevant files, the rest is base angular architecture:

home.component.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="iFrameUrl" ngIf="displayIFrame" style"height:80%; width:80%; z-index:20; 
        position:absolute; background: white" id="IFrameTest">

        <button (click)="onOpenIFrame()">Open IFrame</button>
    <body>
</html>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements Oninit {
    iFrameUrl!: SafeResourceUrl;
    displayIFrame = false;
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
       
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    onOpenIFrame(): void{
        this.iFrameUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/widget');
        this.displayIFrame = true;
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { WidgetComponent } from './widget/widget.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent} },
    { path: 'widget', component: WidgetComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the src field must have brackets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).